# touchpad not working in ubuntu 16.04 in dell inspiron 3521

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Every time I start my computer, trying to use a touchpad or an external mouse does not work. Even after formatting my system and reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 I see that a touchpad or external mouse continue to not work. 
Touchpad is working fine in windows.
When I boot my system using bootable disk of Ubuntu 14 then touchpad works.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a similar problem to the people in [this forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413).

The following command installs the Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server. This package provides the necessary drivers/software to enable use of the touchpad on many laptops.

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

If running this command does not work, please provide more details about your system, specifically:

- what is the brand and model of your computer?
- what is the output of `lspci`?
- if your mouse is a USB mouse, plug it is. What is the output of `lsusb`?

If the `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` command does not work, then any more context you can give will be helpful in further diagnosing your issue.